# Fabric app not creating app on Twitter using SDK v3?

Tags: twitter-fabric

I use Fabric in XCode to build iOS apps with Twitter SDK integration only. The creation of new Fabric apps in conjunction with new iOS app (means usage of new bundle identifier) works perfect and in the Fabric dashboard all apps are listed.

But I'm wondering where I can find my apps on Twitter (apps.twitter.com)?

Update May 2017:

Twitter now offers since SDK v3 to implement Twitter SDK without using Fabric. But you *can* use both together ... Old Fabric apps must me connected to your Twitter account and there will be created an own Twitter app which you can be administrated on https://apps.twitter.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Apps created via Fabric will not appear on apps.twitter.com.